# Need to get Oldest MQMessage From MQQueue

Tags: jsp, monitoring, messaging, ibm-mq

Hi I am new to IBM MQ. Here my requirement is to get the oldest MQMessage from the MQQueue regardless of priority they set and display it in JSP for some monitoring purpose.  In the existing code,

```
qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager);

    int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE | MQC.MQOO_BROWSE|MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED;
    MQQueue eventQueue = qMgr.accessQueue(qName, openOptions, null, null, null);
    MQMessage retrievedMessage = new MQMessage();   
    MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
            gmo.options = MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;
    eventQueue.get(retrievedMessage, gmo);
```

Here i am able to get the MQMessage, but that may not be the oldest one in the queue.  I have no idea about this.  Please help me out is there any way to get that one.

Answer (score 1):

If the queue is FIFO then your browse will return the oldest message.   But if the queue is set for priority delivery then you would have to browse the queue until you found the first message of the lowest priority.  Your code snippet indicates this is an event queue.  If that refers to the SYSTEM.*.EVENT queues then they should always be in FIFO mode.  Even if an administrator changes them to priority delivery, all system event messages are produced at the same priority.

The difficulty you face with priority-ordered messages is that you can ignore lower priorities but not higher priorities.  For example, if you specify a priority of 5 on your browse and any messages exist at priority 4 or lower they will not be returned.  But messages or higher priority will be returned and not just Priority 5 messages but rather Priority 9 messages followed by Priority 8 messages and so on.  So you will not be able to selectively browse the first message in each priority but instead will be obliged to browse until you find the first Priority 0 message to know that you have seen the oldest message on the queue if the queue delivery order is set to Priority.

It may be worthwhile to review the methods in [com.ibm.mq.pcf](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/index.html) to see how to inquire on the queue attributes.  If the queue is FIFO, just browse the first message.  If not, browse the length of the queue saving the first message you get from each priority, compare the timestamp to any message from a higher priority and discard the newer one.

Please note that transactions will affect your ability to browse the messages.  Any message held under syncpoint will be unavailable to your browse.  The oldest message not under syncpoint will be returned.

Finally, if you are trying to determine the health of the queue [Queue Service Interval](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzax.doc/mo10830_.htm) events or [QStatus](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzax.doc/mo13800_.htm) statistics may provide what you need and avoid the overhead of browsing down deep queues.